# Why the first character after a sub is ignored somehow in the regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

Here is what I got in the console of Chrome 78.

```js
console.log('1111'.replace(/(^|[^2])/g, '$12'))
// output "21121212"
```

Why isn't it replacing the first `1` with `12`?

Comment: What result were you expecting? `$1` is a reference to the captured match.

Comment: I think the desired output is `212121212`.

Comment: @YongQuan Yes, I thought so too, but I tested the OP code and in fact the output is `21121212`.

Comment: It is a known issue that JS regex skips the current position after a zero-length match, see linked thread with detailed explanation of the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

I think what's happening is that after replacing a zero-width match, it increments the position in the input string by 1 before searching for the next match. Otherwise, it would get stuck in an infinite loop, continually matching and replacing the same zero-width string.

Since `^` matches a zero-width string at the beginning, it increments the position, skipping over the first character of the string before looking for the next match.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

My guess is that you're trying to write

```
(?<=^)|([^2])
```

> yet, you'd want to check if lookarounds are supported or not.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/AMyqyX/1/)

---

### Method 2

This method also has lookarounds,

```
(?<=^|[^2])
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Oz7GLk/1/)

If you would provide some sample intputs and outputs, there might be some workarounds.

For example, maybe a positive lookahead might be an option to look into:

```
(?=^|[^2]|$)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/Nlfg0t/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AMyqyX/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/AMyqyX/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Your demo doesn't work if you switch from PCRE to ECMAScript.

Comment: Unfortunately, ECMAScript doesn't support lookbehind